# Bluetooth not turning on

Tags: networking, bluetooth

When I click on the switch like button in Settings it doesn't turn on, even though the button looks like it is. It still says 'Bluetooth Turned Off' below. I have turned on my earbuds to see if they would be able to connect but nothing happens.

Tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but that didn't work.

uname -a returns

```
Linux tony-Satellite-C55-C 6.5.0-15-generic #15~
22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC 
Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

journalctl -r -u bluetooth -b -0 returns

```
Jan 29 20:47:03 tony-Satellite-C55-C bluetoothd[617]: Bluetooth management inte>
Jan 29 20:47:03 tony-Satellite-C55-C bluetoothd[617]: Starting SDP server
Jan 29 20:47:03 tony-Satellite-C55-C systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 29 20:46:58 tony-Satellite-C55-C bluetoothd[617]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Jan 29 20:46:57 tony-Satellite-C55-C systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
```

rfkill returns

```
    ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth Toshiba Bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      brcmwl-0          unblocked unblocked
 3 bluetooth hci0              unblocked unblocked
```

lspci returns

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Se00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
ries PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I tried running `sudo dmesg` and I do get some errors:

```
[   24.237131] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[   24.237166] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0930-0225.hcd'
[   24.237188] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0930-0225.hcd'
[   26.252958] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   26.252959] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
```

So it seems like I'm missing some firmware. I'm not sure where I'm supposed to get it from.

When I ran `bluetoothctl` then try `power on` & `scan on` they both came back with "No default controller available"

Comment: Right. I'm new to this Linux thing.

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Memory: 8 GiB
Processor: Intel Core i3-4005U @ 1.70 GHz x 4
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version 42.9

I'm sure there is a command that could done this faster & look neater, but I don't know of it yet.

Comment: `journalctl -r -u bluetooth`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to give you the output. The results are too long for a comment. When I try to put it in an answer the 'code' part stops after the first of 48 lines, turning it into a long block of text that is hard to read.

Comment: We just need the first few lines after the problem occurs. 1. Click on the switch to turn on Bluetooth 2. Immediately do either `journalctl -r -u bluetooth -b -0` or `journalctl -r -u bluetooth -b -0 | head -n 20` and [edit] that into your post

Comment: I don't see any lines with errors there. Are you sure the hardware is detected? Basically look in `dmesg` for anything bluetooth related. Then please post the outputs of `rfkill` (this just lists the wireless enable/disable status) and `lspci`

Comment: I did my best to make the `rfkill` & `lspci` legible, but for some reason no matter how I try to edit it, it comes out as ugly boxes of text. I used both the code button and putting the text in between `.

Comment: If you run `bluetoothctl` in terminal, and run `power on` then `scan on`, and wait few minutes, do you see new devices?

Comment: The problem is "firmware Patch file not found". The firmware is not present in any version of linux-firmware. Have you tried the proprietary drivers at https://askubuntu.com/q/55868/1004020 ?

Comment: I've tried installing both of these:

```sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```
per instructions, then:

```sudo apt install linux-firmware
sudo reboot
```
But even after reboot I'm getting no changes. Could it be that my motherboard doesn't support bluetooth? I probably should have mentioned that I'm not using a dongle. My Android phone and Windows 11 laptop had no problem finding the signal.

Comment: Your motherboard does support bluetooth because there were lines logged with `Bluetooth: hci0`. It's just that Linux needs you to install some driver or firmware (which may or may not exist yet) that we are trying to find

Comment: According to some other fixes I tried, bluetooth is active, loaded, unmasked and running. Yet nothing happens when I try to turn it on in settings.

Comment: Your most immediate goal is to get rid of the `BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried`, `command 0x1003 tx timeout` and `Opcode 0x1003 failed:`. If the kernel (reported by `dmesg`) doesn't have Bluetooth working, nothing in userspace (bluetooth.service, and the settings UI) will work